# What is a safe mass flow rate

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, air, gas, biology

In my machine class, the instructor said that if we use compressed air to clean metal of ourselves then we'll actually get hurt because the pressure is too high.

I am wondering, What is considered a safe mass flow rate that the compressor can extract on let's say a pinky without damaging the skin or the bone of a human.

Comment: Do you mean it like that the metal pieces that are moved by the pressurized air can scratch your skin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have and exact answer but I have a short story. Just out of high school I did some work installing pneumatic doors in prisons. The pressure was quite high (enough to slide couple hundred pond doors) and all the hoses wnet to a central control unit. For some reason I had to yank one of the hoses off. The pressure sliced quite deep into my middle finger. It looked like it was done with a knife. No one I worked with believed me when I told them air did it, but it definately did...

Comment: Just be thankful it was a pneumatic system not a hydraulic one.  A hydraulic cut can essentially inject the oil into you, even if it feels like you were only slightly nicked.  That can lead to some very serious consequences if not properly treated. https://www.constructionequipment.com/injection (first link I found, I'm sure there are more comprehensive sources)